# How to prevent Data to be added if they are overlapping by their datetime?

Tags: c#, task

I have a controller which is following;

```
public class ScheduleController: ControllerBase
{
 private readonly IScheduleService _scheduleService;

public ScheduleController(IScheduleService scheduleService)
{
    _scheduleService = scheduleService;
}

[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ScheduleResponseDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<ActionResult<ScheduleResponseDto>> GetDraftSchedule(int plantCode)
{
    var schedule = await _scheduleService.GetLatestScheduleForPlant(plantCode);
    return Ok(schedule);
}

[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ScheduleResponseDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<ActionResult<ScheduleResponseDto>> PostSchedule(int plantCode, List<ScheduleInputItemDto> scheduleInputItems)
{
    var schedule = await _scheduleService.AddNewSchedule(plantCode, scheduleInputItems);
    return Ok(schedule);
}


[HttpPost("items")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ScheduleResponseDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<ActionResult<ScheduleItemResponseDto>> PostScheduleItem(int scheduleId, ScheduleInputItemDto scheduleInputItem)
{
    var scheduleItem = await _scheduleService.AddItemToSchedule(scheduleId, scheduleInputItem);
    return Ok(scheduleItem);
}

[HttpPut("items/{itemId}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ScheduleResponseDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<ActionResult<ScheduleItemResponseDto>> PutScheduleItem(int scheduleId, int itemId, ScheduleInputItemDto scheduleInputItem)
{
    var scheduleItem = await _scheduleService.ChangeScheduleItem(scheduleId, itemId, scheduleInputItem);
    return Ok(scheduleItem);
}
}
```

User adding new schedule and items to schedule. I need to check if items are overlapping by their start date and end date. I have been trying to find a solution to prevent items to be added if they are overlapping.

In **AddItemToSchedule** method I need to check if they are overlapping.

```
public async Task<ScheduleResponseDto> AddItemToSchedule(int scheduleId, ScheduleInputItemDto scheduleItem)
{
    var scheduleWithId = await _scheduleRepository.GetScheduleById(scheduleId);

    scheduleWithId.AddItem(
    start: scheduleItem.Start,
    end: scheduleItem.End,
    cementType: scheduleItem.CementType,
    now: DateTime.UtcNow);
    await _scheduleRepository.Update(scheduleWithId);

    return scheduleWithId.MapToScheduleDto();
}
```

And Also same thing for ChangeScheduleItem method.

```
public async Task<ScheduleResponseDto> ChangeScheduleItem(int scheduleId, int itemId, ScheduleInputItemDto scheduleInputItem)
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var schedule = await _scheduleRepository.GetScheduleById(scheduleId);
    schedule.UpdateItem(itemId, scheduleInputItem.Start, scheduleInputItem.End, scheduleInputItem.CementType, now);
    await _scheduleRepository.Update(schedule);
    return schedule.MapToScheduleDto();
}
```

The first test is for adding new item to schedule and testing with Task.WhenAll() what if two different user call the endpoint with the same two items at the same time.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GivenScheduleWithNoItems_WhenTwoSimultaneousIdenticalAddItemRequests_ThenOneItemIsAddedAndTheOtherRejected()
{
    //Setup
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var plantCode = fixture.Create<int>().ToString();
    var itemToAdd = new ScheduleInputItemDto
    {
        Start = DateTime.UtcNow,
        End = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        CementType = "CEM-I"
    };

    var addScheduleRequest = NewRequest
        .AddRoute("schedule")
        .AddQueryParams("plantCode", plantCode);
    var latestScheduleRequest = NewRequest
        .AddRoute("schedule")
        .AddQueryParams("plantCode", plantCode);
    var addItemForScheduleRequest = (string scheduleId) => NewRequest
        .AddRoute("schedule/items")
        .AddQueryParams("scheduleId", scheduleId);
    
    // Exercise
    await addScheduleRequest.Post(new ScheduleInputItemDto[]{});
    
    // First let's get the schedule before adding any items. This schedule is currently empty..
    var scheduleBeforeAddition = await latestScheduleRequest.Get<ScheduleResponseDto>();

    var scheduleId = scheduleBeforeAddition.ScheduleId.ToString();
    var addItemRequest = addItemForScheduleRequest(scheduleId);

    // Simultaneously start two tasks that will make the same exact item addition request.
    // This is a race condition, the first request should pass and the second should fail.
    var itemAddResponses = await Task.WhenAll(addItemRequest.Post(itemToAdd, false), addItemRequest.Post(itemToAdd, false));

    //Finally let's get the schedule after the item addition requests. It should have only one item in it.
    var scheduleAfterAddition = await latestScheduleRequest.Get<ScheduleResponseDto>();

    // Verify
    scheduleBeforeAddition.ScheduleItems.Count.Should().Be(0);
    //TEST FAILS HERE - only one of the items should be added and the second should cause a conflict
    scheduleAfterAddition.ScheduleItems.Count.Should().Be(1);
    
    var failures = itemAddResponses.ToList().Where(it => it.IsSuccessStatusCode == false);
    var successes = itemAddResponses.ToList().Where(it => it.IsSuccessStatusCode == true);

    failures.Count().Should().Be(1);
    successes.Count().Should().Be(1);
}
```

The second test is for also checking the same thing during changing the item in the schedule.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GivenScheduleWithItem_WhenTwoClientsAreChangingTheSingleItem_ThenItemModificationShouldHappenInSequence()
{
    //Setup
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var plantCode = fixture.Create<int>().ToString();
    var itemDto = new ScheduleInputItemDto
    {
        Start = DateTime.UtcNow,
        End = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        CementType = "CEM-I"
    };

    var addScheduleRequest = NewRequest
        .AddRoute("schedule")
        .AddQueryParams("plantCode", plantCode);
    var latestScheduleRequest = NewRequest
        .AddRoute("schedule")
        .AddQueryParams("plantCode", plantCode);
    var changeItemForScheduleRequest = (string scheduleId, string itemId) => NewRequest
        .AddRoute($"schedule/items/{itemId}")
        .AddQueryParams("scheduleId", scheduleId);

    //Exercise
    //Make new schedule
    await addScheduleRequest.Post(new List<ScheduleInputItemDto> { itemDto });
    
    var scheduleBeforeChanges = await latestScheduleRequest.Get<ScheduleResponseDto>();
    var scheduleId = scheduleBeforeChanges.ScheduleId.ToString();
    var existingItemId = scheduleBeforeChanges.ScheduleItems.First().ScheduleItemId;
    
    var itemChangeRequest = changeItemForScheduleRequest(scheduleId, existingItemId.ToString());

    // Send two simultaneous item change requests
    var itemChangeResponses = await Task.WhenAll(itemChangeRequest.Put(itemDto, false), itemChangeRequest.Put(itemDto, false));
    
    //Get the schedule after item change requests, should have only one item and the item should have an update counter of only 1
    var scheduleAfterChanges = await latestScheduleRequest.Get<ScheduleResponseDto>();
    
    //verify
    scheduleBeforeChanges.ScheduleItems.Count.Should().Be(1);
    scheduleBeforeChanges.ScheduleItems.First().NumberOfTimesUpdated.Should().Be(0);

    scheduleAfterChanges.ScheduleItems.Count.Should().Be(1);
    scheduleAfterChanges.ScheduleItems.First().NumberOfTimesUpdated.Should().Be(1);
    
    var failures = itemChangeResponses.ToList().Where(it => it.IsSuccessStatusCode == false);
    var successes = itemChangeResponses.ToList().Where(it => it.IsSuccessStatusCode == true);

    //TEST FAILS HERE, as one of the calls should fail
    failures.Count().Should().Be(1);
    successes.Count().Should().Be(1);    
}
```

In conclusion I need to prevent methods to add overlapping items in the schedule.

Example Json Input is the following;

```
{
 "scheduleId": 12132891,
  "plantId": 1213,
  "updatedOn": "2021-12-01T12:44:17Z",
 "scheduleItems": [
  {
  "scheduleItemId": 1,
  "cementType": "CEM-I",
  "start": "2021-11-23T00:00:00Z",
  "end": "2021-11-23T02:15:00Z",
  "updatedOn": "2021-12-01T11:43:17Z"
  },
  {
  "scheduleItemId": 2,
  "cementType": "CEM-II",
  "start": "2021-11-23T03:00:00Z",
  "end": "2021-11-23T10:30:00Z",
  "updatedOn": "2021-12-01T11:43:17Z"
  },
  {
  "scheduleItemId": 3,
  "cementType": "CEM-III",
  "start": "2021-11-23T10:30:00Z",
  "end": "2021-11-23T11:00:00Z",
  "updatedOn": "2021-12-01T11:43:17Z"
  }
  ]
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting a concurrency error in EF?

Comment: actually no, I need to have them to be passed the tests.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're getting a conflict because two requests are updating the same values. Someone has to win!

Comment: I am getting conflict just because of the start and end date time. Imagine that there are machines that are producing cement. And I need to schedule them with feeding cement type but start and end date of cement type are getting conflict when I run the tests and one of them to be rejected.

Comment: Maybe I need to lock something to check if the record exists or not. But I don't know where and how to.